# How to create a file in a directory and write in it?

Tags: files-and-directories, writing

I can't find proper documentation on this but basically I want to

1. open a .txt file to write in Mathematica in a defined path.
2. then I want to write to that file line by line probably
3. close the file

Im looking for the Mathematica equivalent of what in C would be `fopen` -> `fprintf` -> `fclose`

Thank you.

Comment: You can't find proper documentation on this? What about [Files](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Files.html), [Low-Level File Operations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LowLevelFileOperations.html), and [FileOperations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FileOperations.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no printf in Mathematica. But to write to a file, just use `WriteString`. Just make sure to convert everything to string, including any Mathematica expressions, and make sure to use InputForm, to avoid 2D. Also need to add an explicit "\n" at end of each line to get CR.

If you want to append, do not delete the file as below, but use `OpenAppend`.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
fileName = FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "test.txt"}]
If[FileExistsQ[fileName],DeleteFile[fileName]];
file=OpenWrite[fileName,PageWidth->Infinity];
Do[
   WriteString[file,ToString@n<>"\n"];
   If[n == 5, WriteString[file, ToString[InputForm@Sin[x/Pi]] <> "\n"]]
   ,
   {n,1,10}
];
Close[file]
```

Here is the content of the file

```
1
2
3
4
5
Sin[x/Pi]
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you, this was what I was looking for

Comment: Why WriteString and not WriteLine?

Comment: @infinitezero `WriteLine` is fine. I happen to prefer `WriteString` so I can control when to add "\n", as I generate lots of Latex and sometimes I want to write small string in middle of building the full Latex which is not fully done yet, and do not want to insert CR yet. So `WriteString` gives me more control that way. But if someone does not need this control, `WriteLine` is fine solution.