# Problems writing file on Mathematica: how to bypass this

Tags: files-and-directories

I am in the quest of writing on a file (original question: [How to create a file in a directory and write in it?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/286488/how-to-create-a-file-in-a-directory-and-write-in-it#286490)) doing this:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
fileName = FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "TransferFunction.txt"}];
If[FileExistsQ[fileName], DeleteFile[fileName]];
file = OpenWrite[fileName, PageWidth -> Infinity];
den = CoefficientList[Denominator[TFilterLevel1], s];
WriteString[file, ToString["\begin{table}[!htb]\n"]];
WriteString[file, ToString["\caption{Transfer function coefficients.}\n\centering\n"]];
Close[file];
```

I am encountering some issues with this approach.

1. The output is wrong:

   ```
   egin{table}[!htb]
   \caption{Transfer function coefficients.}
   \centering
   ```

   My guess is that Mathematica is interpreting "\b" as something. How can I bypass that?
2. I am getting similar warnings when running the code

   > Syntax::stresc: Unknown string escape \c.

   Again, Mathematica is interpreting `\c` as something.

Any simple way to avoid these problems?

Comment: You may need to escape the backslash: `"\\begin"`.

Comment: as MarcoB says, you need to escape all things that starts with "\" by adding an extra "\\". The exception is only for special characters that have specific meaning  such as "\n" and "\b" and "\t" and so on, This has nothing to do with Mathematica. You need to do this in any programming language (such as C, C++ etc... ) when using strings.